# Undefined references when trying to use Tensorflow-Lite C api built for ARM64, with Android - ndk standalone toolchain for ARM

Tags: c++, c, arm, tensorflow-lite

I cross compiled tensorflow lite C from source for ARM64 using Bazel (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64) and got binary libtensorflowlite_c.so

Now I am trying to compile my C code which uses TFLIte C api functions for arm using android-ndk standalone toolchain but am getting lot of undefined reference errors.

Error Logs:

```
aarch64-linux-android-clang++ -o NC.exe build/main.o -fPIE -pie -lc -lm -ldl -llog -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -march=armv8-a -nodefaultlibs -lc -lm -ldl -llog -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -march=armv8-a -lgcc Tlib/libc++_shared.so Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: libdl.so.2, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: librt.so.1, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: libm.so.6, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: libpthread.so.0, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: libstdc++.so.6, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: libgcc_s.so.1, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: libc.so.6, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `close@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fmod@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `csinf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `clogf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `mktime@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `qsort@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::init(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::overflow(int)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::imbue(std::locale const&)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `lrintf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Backtrace@GCC_3.3'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__once_proxy'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::bad_weak_ptr'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned long)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::underflow()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setdetachstate@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `backtrace_symbols_fd@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::random_device::_M_getval()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ostream::seekp(std::fpos<__mbstate_t>)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::~error_category()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `sigaction@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `sigaltstack@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy::_M_next_bkt(unsigned long) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::thread::join()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_self@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `snprintf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fegetround@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_cond_timedwait@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `atanf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `calloc@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::swap(std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr&)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace_aux(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, char)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `ctanhf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fnmatch@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::_V2::error_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fflush@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `logf@GLIBC_2.27'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ostream::tellp()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `sinh@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `freelocale@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `sched_getaffinity@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `epoll_create1@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ostream::sentry::~sentry()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::rfind(char, unsigned long) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::~ios_base()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `acosh@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `localtime@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__xstat@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `stdout@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__xpg_basename@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `strtoull@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::_V2::error_category'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `getpid@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `getrlimit@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `access@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `sendmsg@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `ccoshf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::uflow()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::erase(unsigned long, unsigned long)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__sched_cpucount@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__xstat64@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__ctype_b_loc@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `atan2@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::future_error'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_condattr_init@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_sync(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `_setjmp@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `catanhf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fputc@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `write@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `strtok_r@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `isdigit@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::istream::read(char*, long)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_last_not_of(char, unsigned long) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::condition_variable::notify_all()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `tolower@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `ftell@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ofstream()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `readdir@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::exception_ptr(void*)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::length_error::length_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `casinh@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_notify_all(unsigned int*)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `ccos@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_cond_wait@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::random_device::_M_init(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `strsignal@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <double, char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::complex<double> const&)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `acoshf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `perror@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `asinf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `getenv@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::ios_base()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::showmanyc()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <float, char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::complex<float> const&)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `sigemptyset@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `log1p@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `rewind@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::istream::tellg()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fcntl64@GLIBC_2.28'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::cout'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::locale::locale()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `raise@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `getc@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy::_M_need_rehash(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `csqrtf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `isatty@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `csinhf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `rand@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_istringstream()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `strtod_l@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `memset@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<double>(double)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `VTT for std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `mkstemps@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ifstream()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `sqrt@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `opendir@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `posix_memalign@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `vtable for std::future_error'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `powf@GLIBC_2.27'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `vasprintf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `_exit@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `isascii@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fchmod@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::_V2::generic_category()'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `setvbuf@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fdatasync@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `tan@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `ctan@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::pbackfail(int)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fesetround@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct(unsigned long, char)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fseek@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::ostream::write(char const*, long)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `dlsym@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__atomic_futex_unsigned_base::_M_futex_wait_until(unsigned int*, unsigned int, bool, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1l> >, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >)'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `shm_open@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `ldexp@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `stpcpy@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `__errno_location@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `getsockname@GLIBC_2.17'
Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so: undefined reference to `fprintf@GLIBC_2.17'
clang60++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [exe] Error 1
```

Currently my c code (main.c) has only printf("%d\n",TfLiteVersion());

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code, Makefile and error messages as code blocks instead of linking to external sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to exactly reproduce your issue, but a good clue is this warning you got:

```
D:\ARM_TOOL\android-standalone\android-ndk-r17-arm64\bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: libc.so.6, needed by Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Your linker is unable to link in the standard C library that was successfully linked during the compilation of `libtensorflowlite_c.so`. On my system, for example, I can find a similar `close@GLIB_2.xx` symbol in my libc.so.6, as shown like this:

```
>> nm -D /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6  | grep 'close'
000328f0 T catclose@@GLIBC_2.0
000f2b70 T __close@@GLIBC_2.0
000f2b70 W close@@GLIBC_2.0
```

So, one thing you could do is just add the path to that exact library on your system in your compilation line just after `Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so`

I would also take the advice of the warning and add `-rpath-link=dir` where `dir` is the directory to the libc.so that was used for the creation of `libtensorflowlite_c.so`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I linked these libraries and was able to sove all the errors.

ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
libc.so.6
libc++.so
libdl.so.2
libm.so.6
libpthread.so.0
librt.so.1
libstdc++.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1

Cheers